# Migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I am trying to upgrade Magento version of my site from Magento 1 to Magento 2. In this case I am using Migration Tool. I used below command

```
php bin/magento migrate:data /php/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.1/config.xml -vvv
```

I am getting following error message.

[image]

Actually I am learning this. I need a basic solution for this.

How can I get a error free result ??

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a different DB structure.  Suggest you read the documentation ( how to extend the migration tool ) and trace the error log to understand what's the difference in the data structure.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html
Specifically this to handle extending the tool for your customized data structure:  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-internal-spec.html

Comment: Thanks @Chuck for your reply. I read these links. But I need a step by step guide on extending migration tool, on tracing error log. I am learning this tool. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By seeing the error message, first of all, you need to put all the tables that are mentioned in `Source documents are not mapped` in the ignore list in file `vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.1/map.xml.dist` as follows :

```
    <source>
            <document_rules>
                <ignore>
                    <document>athlete_bannerslider_slides</document>
                </ignore>

-------
```

Go through the documentation links as shared in the answer Chuck.